# Mutating multiple columns to get 1 or 0 for passfail conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this

```
ID <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A")
Step <- c("Step_1","Step_1","Step_2","Step_2","Step_3","Step_3","Step_3","Step_4")
Passfail <- c("Pass","Pass","Fail","Pass","Fail","Fail","Pass","Fail")
Measurement <- c("Length","Length","Breadth","Breadth",
                 "Height","Height","Height","Width")

df <- data.frame(ID,Step,Passfail,Measurement)
```

I am trying to create several columns that when true should return 1 else 0 GROUPED by (Measurement,ID,ToolID)

For each group,

1. AP = 1 if **only passes** in the passfail
2. AF = 1 if **only fails** in the passfail
3. SFP = 1 if there is **only 1 fail and atleast 1 pass** in passfail
4. MFP = 1 if there are **more than 1 fails and atleast 1 pass** in passfail.

**Desired Output** is

```
  Measurement ID   Step AP AF SFP MFP
       Length  A Step_1  1  0   0   0
      Breadth  A Step_2  0  0   1   0
       Height  A Step_3  0  0   0   1
        Width  A Step_4  0  1   0   0
```

I am trying it this way to get the AP & AF columns but not quite getting it right

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(Measurement,ID,Step) %>% 
  mutate(AP = case_when((Passfail == "Pass" & Passfail != "Fail") ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
         AF = case_when((Passfail == "Fail" & Passfail != "Pass") ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)
         ) %>%
  distinct()
```

Comment: May be change the `&&` to `&`

Comment: Just edited it but it still doesn't give my desired output.

Comment: The logic should be different,.  It can not be bother 'Pass'  and not equal to 'Fail'.  Did you meant `all(Passfail != "Fail")`

Comment: Thanks akrun. I was looking for "all". makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of your approach:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Measurement,ID,Step) %>% 
  summarize(AP = case_when(all(Passfail == "Pass") ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
            AF = case_when(all(Passfail == "Fail") ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
            SFP = case_when(sum(Passfail == "Fail") == 1 & sum(Passfail == "Pass") > 0 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
            MFP = case_when(sum(Passfail == "Fail") > 1 & sum(Passfail == "Pass") > 0 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))
# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   Measurement, ID [?]
#   Measurement ID    Step      AP    AF   SFP   MFP
#   <fct>       <fct> <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Breadth     A     Step_2     0     0     1     0
# 2 Height      A     Step_3     0     0     0     1
# 3 Length      A     Step_1     1     0     0     0
# 4 Width       A     Step_4     0     1     0     0
```

With `all(...)` we require that the condition holds for all the cases of `Passfail`, while with `sum(Passfail == "Fail")` we count the number of failures. With those two techniques we cover all four cases.

Notice, though, that since for each variable you have only two cases, you may also simplify the code a little to

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Measurement,ID,Step) %>% 
  summarize(AP = 1 * all(Passfail == "Pass"),
            AF = 1 * all(Passfail == "Fail"),
            SFP = 1 * (sum(Passfail == "Fail") == 1 & sum(Passfail == "Pass") > 0),
            MFP = 1 * (sum(Passfail == "Fail") > 1 & sum(Passfail == "Pass") > 0))
```

The logical expressions give `TRUE` or `FALSE` and when multiplying by 1 we coerce those logical vectors into a binary ones, as needed.

Comment: Thanks Julius. This works great but with one small change needed. The SFP column for Step_4 should be zero as there are no passes. The AF and SFP are slightly different based on my logic. AF = All Fails and no passes. SFP = Single Fail and Passes. Can you check that?

Comment: @Sharath, to be precise, I did exactly that. It seems by "rest all pass" for SFP you mean that there has to be at least one pass; will fix that. Is "rest all pass" also supposed to mean that in MFP? As for AF, I don't see what's wrong: `all(Passfail == "Fail")` will be true only if all the elements are `"Fail"`.

Comment: AF is totally fine. that works as expected. I mentioned AF here to just show the difference. Yes, you are correct, SFP needs atleast 1 pass along with 1 fail.

Comment: Yes, MFP also needs at least 1 pass. I just edited the question "adding atleast instead of rest all pass". Thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: @Sharath, fixed MFP now as well.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for fixing this. :)

Comment: @Sharath, while `case_when` is good when there are multiple alternatives, in this case you may want to drop it as in the other solution that I've just added.

Comment: yeah totally makes sense. I also wanted to apply it to a bigger data set so I was trying it with case_when.